# What is the AWS Account Id for Heroku in Europe?

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm looking to move our Heroku app from the US to the EU region. As our app uses Amazon RDS as the database I'll need to add the new european Heroku EC2 cluster to the access whitelist.

Does anyone know the new AWS Account ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I needed to move my Amazon RDS instance to the same region as Heroku is in (eu-west-1). I've now got it working!

Answer (score 0):

I had to apply the region option:

rds-authorize-db-security-group-ingress --region eu-west-1 ...